# How do I check if text contains a specific word or similar?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, praw

I'm really new to python and I was wondering if a text is inputted, can I use sequencematcher to check if the text contains a certain word or another word that is 80% similar or above.

For example if the word to check was "**circumflex**", and the text was:

> "In anatomy, **circumflux** describes a structure that bends around
>   like a bow."

it will detect it as a 90% match and then do something, else if the text was:

> "In anatomy, **cercimflux** describes a structure that bends around
>   like a bow."

it will be a 70% match and do nothing.

Is this possible?

Comment: You should look into the Jaro distance between two strings.  There are several libraries that implement it, such as `jellyfish`, that you can install

Comment: The distance (difference) between to strings is called the Levenshtein distance. You might want to look at [this page](http://stackabuse.com/levenshtein-distance-and-text-similarity-in-python/) which explains it in detail with a video, lists modules and shows a python implementation.

Comment: @James I found difflib SequenceMatcher but I only want it to do it in a certain word within a larger text

Comment: Then you can iterate over the string checking each word. IE: for x in my_string: do sequencematching thing.

Answer (score 1):

Based on ThatBird's fuzzywuzzy suggestion with my own additions to check against each word.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

my_string = "this is a test"
comparisons = []
for x in my_string:
    comparisons.append(fuzz.ratio(x, "test!"))
print sum(i > 70 for i in comparisons) #Based on previous example test! would be 97%

Output: 1 #as test was a 97% match
```

Additionally you could save off the word being compared and the comparison value as well so that those could be of futher use.

Comment: Thanks :) this seems to be the best answer! I may try to adapt it for two words as well. It seems like zip can be used in python 3 if I am using two words and iterating two at a time?

Comment: That's true, you could use zip to work w/ tuples in a number of ways.

Answer (score 0):

Try this awesome package [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy)

And it works like -

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
fuzz.ratio("this is a test", "this is a test!")
```

Output - `97`

Comment: I don't want to do it on the whole text, just a certain word in the text. I'm not sure if it's even possible

Comment: My comment above also applies here... simply iterate over the string and then apply the fuzzywuzzy to each word...

Comment: @AlvieMahmud obviously you will need to have a word stored in some kind of variable or list so that you could compare them